# Coloredlettrine Error: Did any one have any luck using the coloredlettrine package?

Tags: xetex, errors, packages, luatex, lettrine

https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/69271/1

^Raphink created the [coloredlettrine package](https://github.com/raphink/coloredlettrine) (https://github.com/raphink/coloredlettrine). I have tried to compile it in XeLaTeX to no avail. I downloaded and installed the font package [EB Garamond](http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/) (http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/) into the same folder as the TeX file, but still, it won't compile. Persistent error: "! LaTeX Error: File `coloredlettrine.sty' not found."

[image: Error Message in Console]

Comment: Did you download the package? As far as I know, the package is not on CTAN (so not on MacTeX/TeX Live).

Comment: I can't find it online, on either CTAN or Raphink's github

Comment: You have to download `coloredlettrine.dtx` and `coloredlettrine.ins` from the GitHub site and run TeX on the `.ins` file, which will create `coloredlettrine.sty`.

Comment: @egreg: it's not so simple, unfortunately. The CTAn distribution of EBGaramond doesn't have all the fonts…

Comment: @Bernard The `EBGaramond-InitialsF1` and `EBGaramond-InitialsF2` fonts are what's needed, which are available at the EB Garamond site. However, the code in `coloredlettrine.sty` has a wrong name for them.

Comment: @egreg: Are you sure? I managed to use them without modifying anything and was going to write an answer to describe the procedure.

Comment: @Bernard Probably it depends where you put the font files.

Comment: @egreg: I installed the latest EB Garamond (.otf files) in my LocalTeXMF\font\opentype\ebgaramond and refreshed the FNDB (I use MiKTeX), that's all. Then generated the doc (not the index not the glossary, as I had  some problems with them).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To have the package work, one has first to download the `coloredlettrine` package from the [link](https://github.com/raphink/coloredlettrine) the OP gave *and* the latest version of the `ebgaramond` opentype fonts, that can download as a .zip file from [here](https://bitbucket.org/georgd/eb-garamond/downloads).

That being done, first install the opentype fonts in a `local` TeXMF directory (crete one if you don't have one, as happens if you're a MiKTeX user), in `YourLocalTeXMF\fonts\opentype\ebgaramond` and refresh the FNDB (MiKTeX)  or run TeXhash (TeX Live).

Next unzip the lettrinecolored package in some directory and run Xe/LuaLaTeX on `coloredlettrine.ins`. This will create the `coloredlettrine.sty` file. Run  again Xe/LuaLaTeX, on coloredlettrine.dtx this time, in order to have the documentation, and on `coloredlettrine-example.tex` to have an example.

Finally place `coloredlettrine.sty` and `lettrine.cfg` in `YourLocalTeXMF\tex\latex\coloredlettrine`,  `coloredlettrine.pdf` and `coloredlettrine-example.pdf` in `YourLocalTeXMF\doc\latex\coloredlettrine`. You may keep the coloredlettrine.zip file that was downloaded in  `YourLocalTeXMF\src` or delete it, as you wish. Refresh the FNDB or run texhash once more.

Below is the example and the first page of the doc.

[image]

[image]

Comment: BeautifuL! Works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks! However I couldn't manage to make the index (correctly) nor the glossary-history (at all).

Comment: Recently, the previously missing initials have been added to EB Garamond on github. So you might consider downloading the font files from [here](https://github.com/georgd/EB-Garamond) instead of the old bitbucket repository.