# How can I install the coloredlettrine package?

Tags: luatex

I tried to do as the following post explained:

> [Coloredlettrine Error: Did any one have any luck using the coloredlettrine package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173662/coloredlettrine-error-did-any-one-have-any-luck-using-the-coloredlettrine-packa)

However, I wasn't able to generate the *coloredlettrine.sty* file by running:

`$ lualatex coloredlettrine.ins`

LuaLaTeX returns the following error:

> LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}

Which steps am I missing, if any?

Answer (score 1):

First, download source code from [raphink/coloredlettrine: EB Lettrine](https://github.com/raphink/coloredlettrine).

Then, download font files from [georgd / EB-Garamond / Downloads — Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/georgd/eb-garamond/downloads/) and then install them.

Finally, run the code below to get `.sty` and `.pdf` file.

```shell
latex coloredlettrine.ins
xelatex coloredlettrine.dtx
makeindex -s gind.ist -o coloredlettrine.ind coloredlettrine.idx
makeindex -s gglo.ist -o coloredlettrine.gls coloredlettrine.glo
xelatex coloredlettrine.dtx
xelatex coloredlettrine.dtx
```

---

You can also run with `l3build`. Create `l3build.lua` in the same directory as `coloredlettrine.dtx`.

In `l3build.lua`:

```lua
module     = "coloredlettrine"
ctanzip    = "coloredlettrine"
typesetexe = "xelatex"
```

You can run

```shell
latex coloredlettrine.ins
l3build doc
```

to get package file and documentation file.

But I found the documentation file has a little different. A big one and a small one. I don't know the reason for this. If anyone knows, you can answer it.

[image]